# Grunt serve Error

Tags: gruntjs

So I tried to install yeoman to my ubuntu 14 and give me message error like this:

```
jonathan@AMRSEVIEW:~/a$ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 1 path cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: Cannot find module 'lodash' Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2015-09-07 08:26:30 UTC)
loading tasks                 9ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 16%
serve                         4ms  ▇▇▇ 7%
loading grunt-contrib-clean   8ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 14%
clean:server                 11ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 19%
loading grunt-wiredep         3ms  ▇▇▇ 5%
wiredep:app                  21ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 37%
Total 57ms
```

Then I tried with grunt serve --force and give me this message error:

```
jonathan@AMRSEVIEW:~/a$ grunt serve --force
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
>> 0 paths cleaned.

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Warning: Cannot find module 'lodash' Used --force, continuing.

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task
Warning: Cannot find module 'lodash' Used --force, continuing.

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

    Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
    Copied 1 file

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2015-09-07 08:27:23 UTC)
    loading tasks                9ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇ 17%
    loading grunt-contrib-copy  23ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 44%
    copy:styles                 19ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 37%
    Total 52ms
    Loading "autoprefixer.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: /home/jonathan/a/node_modules/grunt-autoprefixer/node_modules/autoprefixer-core/node_modules/caniuse-db/data.json: Unexpected end of input
Warning: Task "autoprefixer:server" failed. Used --force, continuing.
Loading "connect.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: /home/jonathan/a/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/node_modules/type-is/node_modules/mime-types/node_modules/mime-db/db.json: Unexpected end of input
Warning: Task "connect:livereload" failed. Used --force, continuing.
Loading "watch.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: /home/jonathan/a/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/node_modules/gaze/node_modules/globule/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:750
>>   /**
>>   ^^^
>> Unexpected token ILLEGAL
Warning: Task "watch" failed. Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.


Execution Time (2015-09-07 08:27:22 UTC)
loading tasks                   21ms  ▇▇ 3%
loading grunt-contrib-clean     19ms  ▇▇ 3%
clean:server                    17ms  ▇ 2%
wiredep:app                     38ms  ▇▇▇ 5%
wiredep:test                    19ms  ▇▇ 3%
loading grunt-concurrent        25ms  ▇▇ 3%
concurrent:server              493ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 68%
loading grunt-autoprefixer      13ms  ▇ 2%
loading grunt-contrib-connect   54ms  ▇▇▇ 7%
loading grunt-contrib-watch     11ms  ▇ 2%
Total 723ms

jonathan@AMRSEVIEW:~/a$
```

How to fix this issues?
I am using yo 1.4.8, bower 1.5.2, grunt-cli v0.1.13 - grunt v0.4.5, nom 2.14.2, node 0.12.7,

Comment: Loos like you need to `npm install lodash`

Comment: You need to install lodash `npm install lodash --save`